# How can I filter a list of names by a group when a name can be in multiple groups?

Tags: powerbi

I have a list of pupil assessment scores and I want to filter that list to only show pupils who are in a certain group. However, one pupil could be in more than one group. For example, if the groups were things like sports teams, I might want to see the names of the people in the football team, or the cricket team, but a pupil might be in both.

I have a table of pupils, a table of the group names and a table of the pupils who are in each group with the relationships show here:

[image]

On my report, the default list of pupils needs to show, and then when a group from the slicer showing the group names is selected, the table showing the scores filters for the pupils in that group.

I could do this with the listID being included in the tbl_score, but that would only allow a pupil to be in one group. How can I structure the data so that tbl_score gets filtered by the list of names which are in the tbl_listgroups?

Comment: do two matches, one for name and one for group, linked with and().

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike. Can you give me a little more detail...when you say do two matches what do you mean? I've created the relationships between the IDs but I'm not familiar with what you mean. Using query editor?

Comment: Try the match() function: match(lookup_value,lookup_array,match_type) excel suggests match_type is optional - I always specify it.